# Element implicitly has an 'any' type when accessing object literal with a non-complete string literal union type (TS 7053)

Tags: typescript

My app has list of `status` literal strings. Some of these statuses have an associated icon name, but not all of them.

I have a function that returns an icon name for a `status`, or `null` if no icon name exists.

```js
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";

const icons = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  return icons[status];
}
```

[Code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnAKuaBeKAiAShAI5IQrC5QA+eA8mMAJYD2AdpTbgMJsBmjAJwC2EACYc8XeKwDGEADbyxE7gIiJlAbgBQ2mW3JRG+1iig4A3tqhRCJMsABceGfOYyA1rgA01qD1Z+YTFnXBkACwhPHz8pWQUlUVCZAWYUFBiAXyh4MxNyHW1eJFkmNiMTADl4EQAxZgE4RFQACnJmlGcm5HRMAEooKxs1ZAFWCoMAbXaegF0oAH4FqFYkRR1MoA)

TypeScript gives me this error, which I don't understand:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'StatusType' can't be used to index type '{ readonly Request: "clock"; readonly Confirmed: "check"; readonly Cancelled: "cross"; }'.
>
> Property 'Option' does not exist on type '{ readonly Request: "clock"; readonly Confirmed: "check"; readonly Cancelled: "cross"; }'.(7053)

How do I fix this error?

In the real code, the `StatusType` is a union from multiple imported objects, so I'd rather not have `icons` contain an exhaustive list of all possible keys.

I tried checking for the key before accessing the object, but the error is still there:

```js
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";

const icons = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  if (status in icons) {
    return icons[status]
  }

  return null
}
```

[Code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnAKuaBeKAiAShAI5IQrC5QA+eA8mMAJYD2AdpTbgMJsBmjAJwC2EACYc8XeKwDGEADbyxE7gIiJlAbgBQ2mW3JRG+1iig4A3tqhRCJMsABceGfOYyA1rgA01qD1Z+YTFnXBkACwhPHz8pWQUlUVCZAWYUFBiAXyh4MxNyHW1eJFkmNiMTADl4EQAxZgE4RFQACnJmlGcm5HRMAEooKxtGXig2hB6jVgqDAaGbKDVkAWnjAwBtdp6AXT9M3RslpBWoViRFbUygA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined [yedidya-rashi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72755556/19415229)'s and [radu-diță](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72755703/19415229) answers to give a solution that fits my criteria:

```
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";

const icons: Partial<Record<StatusType,string>> = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  return icons[status]
}
```

[Code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnAKuaBeKAiAShAI5IQrC5QA+eA8mMAJYD2AdpTbgMJsBmjAJwC2EACYc8XeKwDGEADbyxE7gIiJlAbgBQ2mW3JRG+1igBcUAArwBTePIA8hfQNEO4iVBkgAacgMZWAHMAPhCoHABvbSgoQhIyYAtcGXlmGQBrXB8YqB5WfmExZJkACwhM7NypWQUlURKBZhQUKoBfKHgUKBNyHW1eJFkmNiMTADl4EQAxZgEPZBQACnJPc1gERe8IAEooaNi1ZAFWMYMAbVXFgF1tNqA)

- `Record<StatusType, string>` ensures any key in `icons` must be valid `StatusType`
- `Partial<>` ensures that `icons` doesn't need to contain all `StatusType`s, as some don't have an icon

I also enhanced it so that only valid icons are allowed as `values` in `icons`:

```
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";
type IconName = "clock" | "check" | "cross" | "confirm"

const icons: Partial<Record<StatusType,IconName>> = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  return icons[status]
}
```

[Code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnAKuaBeKAiAShAI5IQrC5QA+eA8mMAJYD2AdpTbgMJsBmjAJwC2EACYc8XeKwDGEADbyxE7gIiJlAbgBQoSFACSMtgDl4IqDlwz5zGQGsVMgBYQHTgcxQonfQUNxtbWNWcihGEJQALigABXgBJnh5AB5CYwFRFLhEVAxIABojU3MIAD4yyygAb20oKEISMmAY61t3ArqoHlZ+YTFWlzdHTvqpWQUlUUHPb1xOgF8oeBQoSOAdbV4kWSY2cJCzEQAxZgEc5BQACnJc6NgES-yIAEoarrVkAVYDthQAbVulwAutoFkA)

Answer (score 0):

When a raw object is defined in Typescript (e.g. `icons`) - it won't allow for indexed access (e.g. `icons[key]`) where key is a string or in your case string litral.

Either `icons[status]` should be of type [`keyof typeof icons`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) or you need to redefine icons to allow for indexing by a random string, but that is less typesafe, since you aren't guaranteeing that you will pass in a valid key.

You can use [`Index Signature`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
const icons : {[key:string]:string} = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
}
```

or [`Record Utility Type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```
const icons : Record<string, string> = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `icons` to only allow for values that are in the `StatusType` Union. You'll need to `Exclude` the values that you don't have entries for and then add specific checks for them inside `iconNameForStatus`.

Something similar to this:

```
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";

const icons: Record<Exclude<StatusType, "Option" | "Created">, string> = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  if (status === "Option" || status === "Created") {
    return null
  }

  return icons[status];
}
```

It would be a lot more readable if you would give default values for missing `StatusType`. Something similar to this:

```
type StatusType = "Request" | "Option" | "Confirmed" | "Cancelled" | "Created";

const icons: Record<StatusType, string> = {
  Request: "clock",
  Confirmed: "check",
  Cancelled: "cross",
  Option: "default",
  Created: "default"
} as const;

function iconNameForStatus(status: StatusType) {
  return icons[status];
}
```

This removes the need for `Exclude` and the extra check inside `iconNameForStatus`.